# Control reach end of non-void function

Tags: objective-c

Please consider following code:

```
-(NSString*)getNextOvulationString{

    if (self.daysToNextOvulation < 0){
       return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Овуляция была %li дней назад", labs(self.daysToNextOvulation)];
    }   else if (self.daysToNextOvulation == 0){
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Овуляция началась"];
    }   else if (self.daysToNextOvulation   > 0){
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Овуляция началась"];
    }
 }
```

There is 3 cases, and obvious, we will get one guaranteed.

Still, compiler not allow me to build, because of error:

> Control reach end of non-void function

How to fix that?

Comment: Don't put the "if" test for the last one. Do `}   else{// if (self.daysToNextOvulation   > 0){` instead, that way you keep for coming back later that it's the case for "> 0". The compiler doesn't check if all the values possibles are checked.

Comment: you know that but compiler doesn't know it. We should always leave one return statement outside of if block or in else as Larme suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the final condition is the exhaustive case, **change the final `else if` to an `else` and call it a day.** If you want, add your condition as a same-line comment to keep it clear.

**The end result would be something like this:**

```
- (NSString *)getNextOvulationString
{
    if (self.daysToNextOvulation < 0)
    {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Овуляция была %li дней назад", labs(self.daysToNextOvulation)];
    }   
    else if (self.daysToNextOvulation == 0)
    {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Овуляция началась"];
    }   
    else // self.daysToNextOvulation > 0
    {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Овуляция началась"];
    }
 }
```

**You could also drop the final `else` altogether like this:**

```
- (NSString *)getNextOvulationString
{
    if (self.daysToNextOvulation < 0)
    {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Овуляция была %li дней назад", labs(self.daysToNextOvulation)];
    }   
    else if (self.daysToNextOvulation == 0)
    {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Овуляция началась"];
    }   

    // self.daysToNextOvulation > 0
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Овуляция началась"];
 }
```

**And since the last two conditions both `return` the same thing you could even write it this way:**

```
- (NSString *)getNextOvulationString
{
    if (self.daysToNextOvulation < 0)
    {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Овуляция была %li дней назад", labs(self.daysToNextOvulation)];
    }
    else // self.daysToNextOvulation >= 0
    {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Овуляция началась"];
    }
 }
```

**Or this way, again dropping the `else` entirely:**

```
- (NSString *)getNextOvulationString
{
    if (self.daysToNextOvulation < 0)
    {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Овуляция была %li дней назад", labs(self.daysToNextOvulation)];
    }

    // self.daysToNextOvulation >= 0
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Овуляция началась"];
 }
```

***Note: All of the above pieces of code are functionally equivalent given the current conditions and return values.***

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `else` at last to return the `NSString`, so change you `if` condition like this.

```
-(NSString*)getNextOvulationString{

    if (self.daysToNextOvulation < 0){
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Овуляция была %li дней назад", labs(self.daysToNextOvulation)];
    }
    else if (self.daysToNextOvulation == 0){
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Овуляция началась"];
    }
    else  //No need to compare here
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Овуляция началась"];
    }
}
```